# How can I make a new data type called Identifier that every instance of it should be a valid identifier name?

Tags: java, class, types

can I make this new class as I asked in the title, this is my attempt.

```
import javax.lang.model.*;

public class Ide{
    public Ide New(String ide){
        if (SourceVersion.isName(ide)) {
            return ide;
        } 
    }
}
```

But it won't compile because I can't convert the String ide to type Ide, how can I do it? I need to have type Ide, thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're doing is confusing. You can check a string and return whatever the `Ide` is supposed to be without it being a `String` too. Read about [final classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).

Comment: Not possible. Only `Object` can be used as an "*any object*" reference type. You could always wrap the object you are trying to reference.

Answer (score 2):

This code has several issues:

- `String` is `final`. This means, no class can inherit from `String`.
- `New` should be `static`, otherwise the method won't make any sense. Requiring an instance of a class to create other instances is like the chicken-and-egg-problem, only you haven't got either one.
- calling a method `New` is **really bad** style. `new` is a keyword in java and you're provoking coding errors, make your code less readable... . And method names shouldn't be uppercase.
- Even if it was possible to make a class extend from `String`, a `String`-parameter wouldn't automatically be an `Ide`-instance. Thus the `return ide;` won't compile.

A solution to your problem would be:
Use a `private` constructor combined with a `static` factory-method. The class can only be a wrapper-class though. Simply implement it in adapter-style to provide the methods provided by `String` that are required:

```
class Ide{
    private String str;

    private Ide(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }

    public static Ide createIde(String str)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if(validIdentifier(str))
            return new Ide(str);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid identifier: " + str);
    }

    //examples for adapter-like method-implementation
    public String toString(){
        return str.toString();
    }

    public char charAt(int i){
        return str.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong on many many levels. I suggest that you first learn about the fundamentals of Java; before you consider writing your own code.

Problems in your code:

1. Java String class is **final**, that means that no other class can inherit from String (so Ide can not extend String)
2. You are calling your method "New". That is a superbad name for a method. Call it for example: "generateIdeFromName()".
3. The compiler tells you what is wrong: a String object is not an Ide object. Therefore you can't assign String to Ide (and that is what happens your method that is supposed to return an Ide object returns a String)

Long story short: you are trying to build a skyscraper, but you are already lacking the skills to dig a whole in the ground. This is not meant to insult you, but the fact is: you have to do a lot of learning first. Don't expect us to explain everything to you that you would need to come up with a reasonable program.